# Override default User model method

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to override the default `__unicode__()` method for the django.contrib.auth.models User model but I can't get it to work.

I tried it like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class User(models.Model):
        def __unicode__(self):
            return "pie"
```

and

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class User(User):
        def __unicode__(self):
            return "pie"
```

but it's not working, I know it's wrong like that but I have no idea how to do it properly.

All I want it to do is to say "pie" instead of the user name inside the admin panel.

edit:

Managed to do it like this:

```
class MyUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.get_full_name() == '':
            return "pie"
        else:
            return self.get_full_name()
```

I used the MyUser class when making ForeignKey references, instead of User.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. I wasn't try to be mean regarding MonkeyPatching, but if you are going to go down that road you really need to be ready to deal with all sorts of interesting problems. In particular you have to be prepared for it to break on any given update to the underlying Django core code.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at Django's [Proxy Model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#id8) concept. They even show an example using User as a base class.

On the other hand, if you are trying to change the actual __unicode__() method in the actual User class, you probably will have to [MonkeyPatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) it. It's not difficult, but I'll leave the specifics as a learning experience for you.