# How to override default user model field in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

The problem is the default User model does not have some very useful options given to the fields e.g **unique=True** to the email field.

I read this question: [Override default User model method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817244/django-override-default-user-model-method), and checked [Proxy Model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#id8) concept, but with no effect.

At first I tried:

```
from django.contrib.auth import models
class User(models.User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    email = EmailField('e-mail address', unique=True, blank=False)
```

which resulted in:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Proxy model 'User' contains model fields.
```

so next was:

```
from django.contrib.auth import models
class User(models.User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    models.User.email = EmailField('e-mail address', unique=True, blank=False)
```

and this "solution" has no effect at all. Default User model was behaving the same as before.

I am interested in non-monkey-patching-solution only.

**Edit:** Ok. Monkey-patching is acceptable for me, but how make this reasonably? (I mean not changing the file that lies in `/usr/pyshared/python2.6/...`)

Comment: Ah, come on ... just a *little* bit of monkey business? :-) Unfortunately I don't think you're going to find what you really want. *Everybody* wants to tweak the User model in one way or another, but you have discovered that Django database "classes" are *not* Python classes, particularly with regard to overriding fields in the parent. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted

Comment: Monkey patching would be good enough if the language itself supports it internally ;-) E.g classes in Ruby are open, so You can change implementation of, even built-in, classes at runtime thus the User model could be tweaked in Ruby in at most 3 lines.

Anyway, thank You for Your response. Do You know how to make this monkey-patching reasonable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this already asked... [How to make email field unique in model User from contrib.auth in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160030/how-to-make-email-field-unique-in-model-user-from-contrib-auth-in-django)

Also the django method of additional user data is here http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#auth-profiles .

I'm not entirely a fan of this method and appreciate where you are coming from, but sometimes you have to go with the herd.

Comment: Thank You for Your response. First of all I am searching for a way to add to User model not only email field uniqueness validation. Solution of writing own form that check uniqueness of an email is that one I want to avoid (first link). Why? I think the better way is to add validation deeper. On the other hand, I can add email field to UserProfile model, but this doubles information in DB. *sigh* But I think I'll stick the form validation method.