# django override User model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to override the default User model in Django to add some logic into the save() method. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out out to go about this.

I'm using Django 1.1 if that helps.

I used post_save since i need to add the user into ldap.. I just added this into a models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import dispatcher


def user_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print "got here"

models.signals.post_save.connect(user_post_save, sender=User)
```

Comment: You can look at Proxy Models: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models. By the way: there are plenty of questions like Yours (e.g. mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263533/)

Comment: @Dejw, I've tried proxy model before but I think it messes up url from auth like when you access the admin site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't. Instead catch the [`pre_save` signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch).

Comment: How? What would he do in the `pre_save` signal? Can you give an example of how to do it?

Comment: @Dominic: The signal handler is passed the model before it's put into the database. You just manipulate it the way you normally would.

Comment: @dominic.. i updated my post with a example solution based on post_save signal

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use a Proxy model, so to use the same table but overriding behavior.

This is the standard way to extend Django's own models, because they cannot be made abstract.

So declare your model as:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CustomUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do anything you need before saving
        super(CustomUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # do anything you need after saving
```

and you are done.

Comment: I used proxy models and it breaks up couple of things such as urls in the admin site. Don't think its a good choice.

Comment: Right. Now that I know much more django than 7 months ago, I'd go straight to the signal path.