# How do I allow groups to access the admin page with an is_staff property?

Tags: python-3.x, django, webserver

I have 3 groups and I want two to be able to access the admin page with different permissions. I'm just building off the base user model. The closest I feel I've gotten is from a previous Stackoverflow post [Django admin is_staff based on group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284422/django-admin-is-staff-based-on-group)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class User(User):

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        if user.groups.filter(name="Level2").exists():
            user.is_staff = True
        else:
            user.is_staff = False
```

Comment: When you say "admin oage" you mena Django admin or you mean some admin pages in your application?

Comment: The base admin page under /admin.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: AFAIK Django does not handle various permissions inside admin. You are admin (is_staff) or you are not. But you can limit actions on your models through standard group/user permissions and they will be valid inside admin too. It depend what you wish to manage inside admin interface.